# Difference between LINQ statements? Position of select

Tags: .net, linq

Is there a difference between the following LINQ statements?

```
var value  = source.Select(y => y.Id).Where(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y)).ToList();

var value  = source.Where(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.Id)).Select(y => y.Id).ToList();
```

In terms of data loading and performance.

Comment: Even if there were any differences, it's not worth losing sleep over. As far as you, me, or anyone else (besides compiler nerds) is concerned, they're equivalent statements.

Comment: okay, so only the position of the ToList() is important. If I would add a second ToList() (let's say after the Select statement) it would download all the datasets and reduce the performance. Right?

Comment: Yes, but **only** if you're using Linq-to-Objects and _not_ Linq-to-Entities (i.e. .Entity Framework) - or anything involving `IQueryable<T>` and `Expression<Func<...>>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` and "normal" `Func<>` delegatee; otherwise that changes everything and requires an entire reexplanation.

Comment: Which one is faster? Well, test it and find out! We have no idea what `source` is here. Is it a `List<T>`? Is it an Entity Framework DbSet? It is impossible for us to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran some benchmarks on this:

```cs
[MemoryDiagnoser(false)]
public class Benchmarks
{
    private DataObject[] Data { get; set; }

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        Data = new DataObject[1000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < Data.Length; i++)
        {
            Data[i] = new DataObject
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            };
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void WhereSelect()
    {
        var newColl = Data.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Id)).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void SelectWhere()
    {
        var newColl = Data.Select(x => x.Id).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();
    }
}


public class DataObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The array gets filled with 1,000,000 elements, where I execute both methods on.
This is the result (`BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmarks>()`):

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WhereSelect | 17.12 ms | 0.341 ms | 0.778 ms | 16 MB |
| SelectWhere | 20.83 ms | 0.549 ms | 1.619 ms | 16 MB |

So you can clearly see `.Select(...).Where(...)` is faster. But of course, this is a very large array. For an array of 1000 elements, this is the result:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WhereSelect | 5.955 us | 0.1180 us | 0.1359 us | 16.31 KB |
| SelectWhere | 9.415 us | 0.1596 us | 0.1493 us | 16.31 KB |

Notice how it is about *microseconds* now. But we still have a clear winner.

**Be aware that this only tests the `IEnumerable` implementation of `Where` and `Select`. For the `IQueryable` it might be completely different.**